# How to run NUnit Test for method that takes List<> as one of its parameter and uses foreach loop inside?

Tags: c#, oop, nunit

```
private int _scannedx, _scannedy;

public int ScannedX
{
    get
    {
       return _scannedx;
    } set
    {
       _scannedx = value;
    }
}

public int ScannedY
{
   get
   { 
      return _scannedy;
   } set
   {
      _scannedy = value;
   }
}

public void Scanning(List<Specimen> specimens, Rover rover)
{
   foreach (Specimen specimen in specimens)
   {
       ScannedX = specimen.X;
       ScannedY = specimen.Y;
   }
{
```

Assume that there are 2 specimens that can be scanned because they are in the scannable zone of the Radar on a Rover. The Radar will return specimen's location.

```
[Test()]
public void Scanning()
{
    Radar radar = new Radar("Curiousity");

    //Rover's location || Rover's X = 1, Rover's Y = 2
    Rover rover = new Rover(1, 2);

    //These rocks are in scannable zone
    Specimen rocka = new Specimen(3, 4);
    Specimen rockb = new Specimen(2, 2);
    //This rock is out the scannable zone (cannot be scanned)
    Specimen rockc = new Specimen(10, 15);

    List<Specimen> spciments = new List<Specimen>() { rocka, rockb, rockc };

    radar.Scanning(spciments, rover);

    //Test is successed with these value
    Assert.AreEqual(2, radar.ScannedSpecimenX);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, radar.ScannedSpecimenY);

    //Test is failed with these value || But succeed when removed rockb
    Assert.AreEqual(3, radar.ScannedSpecimenX);
    Assert.AreEqual(4, radar.ScannedSpecimenY);
    //I am looking for a test that can returns both rocka and rockb location.
}
```

I use `Assert.AreEqual` to do the `NUnit` Test but it only allows me catch value from the nearest specimen.

For example: specimen1 has X = 3, Y = 4; specimen2 has X = 1, Y = 2. The current UNnit Test only see specimen2 values.

Is there anyway to deal with the issue?

Comment: Please give a better code sample for what you want to achieve. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've put my NUnit test code. Thank you so much.

Comment: Where is "_radar" defined? Did you mean to use the radar constructed on the first line instead?

Comment: My bad, it's a typo "_"

Comment: I'm going to submit an answer so I can speak with code.